# How to make a list formed by changing some defaults in multiple ways

Tags: python

I have a list of default dictionaries:

```
default = [{"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}, {"One": 5, "Two": 6, "Three": 7},
{"One": 9, "Two": 10, "Three" : 11}]
```

All with the same keys. I have a separate dictionary from key to list:

```
varying = {"One": [12,13,14,15], "Two": [20,21,23], "Three": [12,44]}
```

What I want to do is make a list of all dictionaries possible made by changing one of the values in one of the default dictionaries to one of the corresponding values in the varying dictionary. Here are examples of dictionaries in the final list:

```
{"One": 12, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}
{"One": 13, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}
{"One": 14, "Two": 6, "Three": 7}
{"One": 15, "Two": 10, "Three": 11}
{"One": 5, "Two": 20, "Three": 7}
{"One": 9, "Two": 23, "Three": 11}
{"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 44}
```

So overall there are (4+3+2)*3=27 possibilities.
I was able to get it near working but the problem is it got very messy. Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: Are you talking about the cross product one? I only want to change one element of a default dictionary. Combinations doesn't work either. I can't tell any that actually fit what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
default = [{"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}, {"One": 5, "Two": 6, "Three": 7},
           {"One": 9, "Two": 10, "Three" : 11}]
varying = {"One": [12,13,14,15], "Two": [20,21,23], "Three": [12,44]}

result = [dict(d.items() + [(k, x)])
              for d in default for k, v in varying.items() for x in v]

>>> result
[{'One': 1, 'Three': 12, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 1, 'Three': 44, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 1, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 20},
 {'One': 1, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 21},
 {'One': 1, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 23},
 {'One': 12, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 13, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 14, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 15, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 2},
 {'One': 5, 'Three': 12, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 5, 'Three': 44, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 5, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 20},
 {'One': 5, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 21},
 {'One': 5, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 23},
 {'One': 12, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 13, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 14, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 15, 'Three': 7, 'Two': 6},
 {'One': 9, 'Three': 12, 'Two': 10},
 {'One': 9, 'Three': 44, 'Two': 10},
 {'One': 9, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 20},
 {'One': 9, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 21},
 {'One': 9, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 23},
 {'One': 12, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 10},
 {'One': 13, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 10},
 {'One': 14, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 10},
 {'One': 15, 'Three': 11, 'Two': 10}]
```

Here is the equivalent using normal for loops instead of a list comprehension:

```
result = []
for d in default:
    for k, v in varying.items():
        for x in v:
            result.append(dict(d.items() + [(k, x)]))
```

Note that on Python 3.x you will need to use `list(d.items())` instead of just `d.items()`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is:

```
[ { "One":d["One"], "Two":d["Two"], "Three":d["Three"], i:v }
  for d in default
  for i in ["One","Two","Three"]
  for v in varying[i]
]
```

or

```
[ dict( list(d.items()) + list({i:v}.items()) )
  for d in default
  for i in ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  for v in varying[i]
]
```

or

```
[ dict( list(d.items()) + [(i,v)] )
  for d in default
  for i in ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  for v in varying[i]
]
```

When tested, all three produce the expected result consisting of 27 elements.

Also note that for much bigger datasets these forms could exceed execution time constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Without `itertools`:

```
default = [{"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}, {"One": 5, "Two": 6, "Three": 7},
{"One": 9, "Two": 10, "Three" : 11}]
varying = {"One": [12,13,14,15], "Two": [20,21,23], "Three": [12,44]}
variations = []

for dic in default:
    for key in varying:
        for val in varying[key]:
            new_dict = dict(dic)
            new_dict[key] = val  
            variations.append(new_dict)

print variations
```

If you're not using `itertools`, then this code needs to have at the very least those three loops, it's simply in the nature of your question.

Comment: Why are you converting the dicts in default to dict?

Comment: If I simply did `new_dict = dic` the two would be the same, so instead of having 27 dictionaries, `variations` would have 27 items, but it would only be multiple instances of the three original dictionaries.